# OAuth Named Credential Callout Failure

Tags: apex, integration, oauth2, namedcredentials

I have created a named credential that points to the Microsoft graph API.

My credential has been authenticated successfully but when I try to use it from Apex it fails. 
I am unable to debug , The code I am using is :

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:Azure_AD/users/xyz?api-version=1.6');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

I am getting the below error:

```
08:19:50:598 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>Request_BadRequest</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en">The MIME type 'text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2,application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;q=0.001' requires a '/' character between type and subtype, such as 'text/plain'.</m:message></m:error>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it by adding

```
req.SetHeader('Accept','application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8');
```